# CheckBox в ListBox и всё что с этим связано

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

Доброго времени суток!
Возникла проблема заполнения элемента WPF под названием ListBox, а если конкретнее, то мне нужно "запихнуть" объект типа `List<int>` в ListBox с CheckBox'ами. Всё это нужно для того, чтобы потом пользователь мог поставить галочки напротив нужных ему int'ов, нажать на специальную кнопочку и все отмеченные int'ы записались бы в новый `List<int>`. С записью в ListBox я справился, а вот как вытащить из ListBox'а отмеченные значения... вот тут то и проблема. Вот мой код:

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" SelectionMode="Multiple" Margin="10,10,357,20" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" IsChecked="False"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

C#:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listOfNumbers = new List<int>();
        listOfNumbers.Add(1);
        listOfNumbers.Add(5);
        listOfNumbers.Add(34);

        ListBox1.ItemsSource = listOfNumbers; 
    }
```

Результат работы программы: http://i024.radikal.ru/1402/7a/3280c9d97c86.jpg

Теперь, скажем, я хочу выбрать второй и третий элементы ListBox'а, нажать кнопочку "Сортировать" и чтобы эти элементы попали в новый `List<int>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не-не, не так. Никакого `List<int>`. Смотрите. Какая семантика того, что вы собираетесь показывать? Это нифига не `int`, это пара из `int` и `bool`.

---

Лирическое отступление: вам ещё ваш архитектор не выписал внушение за логику в OnClick? Сходите к нему, получите втык.

---

Таким образом, на уровне VM имеем:

```
class IntWithChoiceVM : DependencyObject
{
    public int Value
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Value", typeof(int), typeof(IntWithChoiceVM));

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSelectedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
                 "IsSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(IntWithChoiceVM));
}

class ListChoiceVM : DependencyObject
{
    public ListChoiceVM(List<int> initial)
    {
        Values = new ObservableCollection();
        foreach (var n in initial)
            Values.Add(new IntWithChoiceVM() { Value = n, IsSelected = true });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<IntWithChoiceVM> Values { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<int> GetSelectedInts()
    {
        return Values.Where(v => v.IsSelected).Select(v => v.Value);
    }
}
```

Отлично, теперь View тривиален:

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Value}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Всё заработало! Честно говоря, не ожидал, что потребуется столько телодвижений для заполнения ListBox'a :) В вашем коде я почти всё понял, но хотел бы как новичок попросить объяснить на пальцах записи, начинающиеся с "public static readonly DependencyProperty" после каждого из двух свойств класса IntWithChoiceVM. Почему нельзя просто заполнять/получать данные с помощью get;set;?

Comment: @xeeqqw: это стандартное объявление DependencyProperty. Вам не нужно писать его вручную, для этого у VisualStudio есть сниппет `propdp` (напишите в новой строке `propdp` и нажмите TAB дважды). Преимущество перед обычными свойствами состоит в том, что если в `IntWithChoiceVM` поменяется какое-то из значений, UI увидит эти изменения и подхватит их. Конкретно в вашем сценарии это может быть и не нужно, но лучше всегда делать так и не думать.

Comment: У автора так было отлично коротко. А код который дальше не работает ссс.

Comment: @aldan: У меня всё работает (с). Коротко не значит хорошо, отделение контента от представления требует большего объёма кода, никуда от этого не уйти. Хотя я с позиций сегодняшнего дня переписал бы на INPC.